# Do I pay my debt payment at the beginning or ending of the due date?

Tags: recettear-an-item-shops-tale

I'm currently on the seventh day of gameplay in Recettear and the eighth day, the first day of payment, fast approaches. However, in planning out my next two days, I've bumped into a situation where my plan of action depends on whether or not the debt payment is payed at the beginning or ending of the day. If it's paid at the beginning, I'm going to head back to the shop and spend the seventh day selling enough expensive weapons and armor to blow past the required amount of money. If it's paid at the end, I'm going to go adventuring and spend the eighth day selling.

Do I pay the debt payment at the beginning or ending of the day?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the 8th day (or whichever day your next payment is due), you will have the entire day to use the time to do whatever you need to in order to make the payment. At the end of the day is when Tear will ask you to pay up, and you'll either successfully make the payment and continue through the game, or end up living in a cardboard box.

I'm not joking. Most guilt-inducing Game Over screen *ever*.

[image]

Comment: Fortunately, it doesn't end there...